# how can i call a function from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the same result after quiz ends without clicking the Results button
Here is what I've tried

```
if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById("quizEnds");
        outputDiv.innerHTML = "You have reached the final question.";
        $('#next').remove();
        getScore(this.form);

    }
```

it does not work. can someone point out the error please. it has to be two separated files. thanks

```js
//quizeffect.js
var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();
var currentQuestion = 0;
$questions = $('.questions');
$questions.hide();
$($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
$('#next').click(function () {
     $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function () {
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById("quizEnds");
            outputDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>You have reached the final question.</h2>";
            $('#next').remove();
          getScore(this.form);
             
        } else {
            $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
        }

    });
    
});
//tlcquizzapp.js
/*====================app js====================*/
var numberOfQuestions = 6;
// Insert number of choices in each question
var numberOfChoices = 4;
var rightAnswers = 0;
var correct = [];
var wrong =[];

var answers = new Array("Double Parking", 
  "The aplicant will have the aplication denied", "Never", "All of the above", 
  "Yellow taxi medallion base", "You are allowed to pick up in the crosswalk if the passenger is standing at the intersection");

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function buildList(arr) {
  var listHTML = '<ol>';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    listHTML += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
  }
  listHTML += '</ol>'; 
  return listHTML;
}

// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    currElt = i * numberOfChoices;
    for (j = 0; j < numberOfChoices; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
          correct.push(currSelection.value);
        }
        else{
            wrong.push(currSelection.value);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score/numberOfQuestions*100);
  var userAnswers = '<p>You got ' + score + ' % on your test.</p>';
  userAnswers += '<h2>You got these answers correct:</h2>';
  userAnswers += buildList(correct);
  userAnswers += '<h2>You got these answers wrong</h2>';
  userAnswers += buildList(wrong); 
  print(userAnswers);
  }
```

```css
.questions p{
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color: #3399FF;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 20px;

}

.options li{
 font-size: 18px;
}
form {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid #DDD;

}

button {
border: none;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #3399FF;
color: #FFF;

}
button:hover {
background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TLC Driver Practice Quiz</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tlc-style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div><h1>TLC Practice Quiz</h1></div>


<form>
<div class="questions">
 <p>1. Which of the following is not a moving violation?</p>
 <ol type="A" class="options">
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q1" value="Double Parking">Double Parking</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q1" value="Tailgating">Tailgating</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q1" value="Speeding">Speeding</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q1" value="Failing to signal a turn">Failing to signal a turn</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<div class="questions">
 <p>2. What is the penalty for an aplicant of an TLC driver's license who test positive for drugs and fails the drug test?</p>
 <ol type="A" class="options">            
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q2" value="The aplicant must take the test again">The aplicant must take the test again</li>           
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q2" value="The aplicant will have a provationary license">The aplicant will have a provationary license</li><li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q2" value="The aplicant will have the aplication denied">The aplicant will have the aplication denied</li>   
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q2" value="The aplicant will have to drive carfolly">The aplicant will have to drive carfolly</li>      
 </ol>  
</div>
              
<div class="questions">
 <p>3. In wich situation may you pass a school bus with the red flashing light on?</p>        
 <ol type="A" class="options">            
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q3" value="When it is snowing">When it is snowing</li>            
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q3" value="When you do not see children around">When you do not see children around</li>            
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q3" value="When someon behind beeps the horn">When someon behind beeps the horn</li>           
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q3" value="Never">Never<br/>       
 </ol>
</div>

<div class="questions">
 <p>4. Wich of the following is a service animal?</p>
 <ol type="A" class="options">
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q4" value="A seeing eye dog">A seeing eye dog</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q4" value="A guide dog">Aguide dog</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q4" value="A signal dog">A signal dog</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q4" value="All of the above">All of the above</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<div class="questions">
 <p>5. Which of the following is not a For-Hire base?</p>
 <ol type="A" class="options">
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q5" value="Yellow taxi medallion base">Yellow taxi medallion base</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q5" value="Black car base">Black car base</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q5" value="Livery car service base station">Livery car service base station</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q5" value="Luxury limousine base">Luxury limousine base</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<div class="questions">
 <p>6. Wich of the following is not correct?</p>
 <ol type="A" class="options">
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q6" value="When you pick up a passenger, the vehicle should be 12 inches from yhe curb">When you pick up a passenger, the vehicle should be 12 inches from yhe curb</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q6" value="When you pick up a passenger, the vehicle should be parallel to the curb">When you pick up a passenger, the vehicle shouldbe parallel to the curb</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q6" value="If the passenger is waiting next to a car that is already parked, you should look for space within 100 ft.">If the passenger is waiting next to a car that is already parked, you should look for space within 100 ft.</li>
  <li><input class="option" type="radio" name="q6" value="You are allowed to pick up in the crosswalk if the passenger is standing at the intersection">You are allowed to pick up in the crosswalk if the passenger is standing at the intersection</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<div id="quizEnds"></div>
<button type="button" name="nextButton" id='next' value="Next">Next</button> 
<button class="results" type="button" value="Results" onClick="getScore(this.form);">Results</button>
<!-- <button type="reset" value="Clear Answers">Clear Answers</button> -->

<div id="output"></div> 

</form>
   

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tlcquizzapp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quizeffect.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is going wrong exactly? Are you seeing any errors in the error console? What method are you using to call the the function from another JS file at the moment? Your title suggests you're asking for how to do that, but your question seems to be about something else.

Comment: Just change: `getScore(this.form);` to `getScore($('form')[0]);`.

Comment: Your help is well appreciated, thank you. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the form element to your `getScore()` function, but `this.form` does not represent the form element at that place in the code because it is inside the callback function passed to `$questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut()`. At that point `this` refers to the question element. And even if you had a reference to the button element at that point, you could not get the form from it because the button has been removed from the page.

You could keep a reference to the form element in a variable where `this` does refer to the button element:

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    var form = this.form;
```

And then use that when calling `getScore()`:

```
getScore(form);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the button. Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse to the form it is within

Try

```
getScore($(this).closest('form')[0]);
```

Or simpler, give the form an id

```
<form id="myForm>
```

And use that id to target form

```
 getScore($('#myForm')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a jQuery event function **this** refers to the element that the event is wired to. You therefore need to refer to the document.form[0], or use a jQuery version of the same.